# How do you control action sheet animation direction

Tags: iphone, uikit

As noted in the Apple developer docs for [showFromTabBar](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/showFromTabBar:), it says:

> The style of the animation depends on the style of the toolbar, not the receiver.

When I use this method as opposed to the `showInView` method, it slides in from above, not from below.

I am using `showFromTabBar` because if I don't, the cancel button is partially untouchable due to some funkiness with the tab bar, which is behind it(pfft).

**Question: how do you make the action sheet animate in from the bottom, as it would normally with `showInView`?**

**Note:** my problem with the tab bar getting in the way has been solved by passing the entire window as the `UIView` via `showInView` as follows:

```
[filterActionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];
```

[Solution to UIActionSheet cancel button problem](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1800450).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem with the cancel button. It is because the bottom bar "hides" the touches from getting through to the action sheet.  You can simple disable user interaction on that view until the action sheet is dismissed and then reenable it.