# UISearchDisplayController,UINavigationController,UITabBarController Woes

Tags: iphone, navigationcontroller, tabbarcontroller

Hey everyone, running into a bit of an issue,

I have created all my views through IB, with the main window having a NavigationController, and a TabBarController which loads a TableViewController in its first tab.

The problem happens when i use the searchbarcontroller in the navigation controller, everything works fine with the exception that when the navigation bar at the top disappears, the table expands too high, and i can't figure out what im doing wrong.

Attached is an image of what im referring to, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[alt text http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/4706/picture1ot.png](http://img263.imageshack.us/img263/4706/picture1ot.png)

Some more information:

i have my MainWindow with a UINavigationController, and a UITabBarController.  On the first Tab, i have it loading another nib "AVN_TableController" which is a UITableViewController nib, with the Searchbar delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going the route of creating my own tabbarcontroller, as that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you've set your view sizes correctly in Interface Builder and are using the "Simulated Interface Elements" to cause the status bar, navigation bar, and tab bar to display, it should work correctly. If not, then what comes to mind is [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197746/uiactionsheet-cancel-button-strange-behaviour) where displaying an action sheet has it's tappable rectangle offset by the height of the tab bar because it is added to the wrong view. Not sure if that would apply here, but it's at least something to consider.

Comment: thanks, ill look into this and let you know.  Yeah, i have the simulated interface elements  showing.