# Pressing Cancel button doesn't retract

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am implementing an action sheet. When I press "ok" button, do these, press "cancel" go back. The  "ok" button is working fine, but when I press the "cancel" button, nothing happens, it doesn't retract or do anything, just hang at the actionsheet view.

Below is my code:

To create button on the nav bar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *clearButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Clear     History"
                                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(ClearHistoryAction:)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = clearButton;
```

When I click and launch action sheet:

```
   - (IBAction)ClearHistoryAction:(id)sender
  {
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Clear History?"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];


// use the same style as the nav bar
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle;    

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];


    }
```

if select ok do this:

```
  - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet

 didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex
  {
if (!buttonIndex == [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex])
{

    //do what i want here!
}
  }
```

In the header file, `UIActionSheetDelegate` is included in `@interface`.

Answer (score 1):

Late but, a possible Explanation could be :

> Seems to be an issue with the tabbar. If you call UIActionSheet's

```
[sheet showInView:self.view]
```

> from a view controller that is a child of a UITabViewController, then
>   the hit testing on the cancel button fails in that portion of the
>   UIActionSheet that lies above the tabbar's view.

If you instead pass in the UITabBarController's view, then the UIActionSheet acts as expected.

```
[sheet showInView:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view];
```

A more detailed explanation here:
[UIActionSheet cancel button strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197746/uiactionsheet-cancel-button-strange-behaviour)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll solve this problem but you'll want to do `buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]` (check not-equal) instead of `!buttonIndex == [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]` (invert `buttonIndex` (!) and check if that's equal).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use showFromBarButtonItem instead of showInView.  The problem is that the cancel button is being covered by another view--maybe a toolbar or tabbar--so it's not getting the touch events you think it should get.  There are also showFromTabBar and showFromToolbar that should sometimes be used (see the UIActionSheet class reference).