# UIActionSheet cancel button not dismissing actionsheet

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

I have an UIActionSheet and I am specifying the cancel button however it does not dismiss when its tapped?

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Target Complete" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease]; 
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

According to the documentation I don't need any code and even when I try and implement the didCancel delegate method its never called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to display from a taskbar or a toolbar on iPhone as it clips some of the controls if you use display in view.

Answer (score 42):

Try this

```
[actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];
```

[UIActionSheet cancel button strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197746/uiactionsheet-cancel-button-strange-behaviour)

Comment: @nevan king: This is not work for me then I didnt use any tabbar or taskbar. I m using navigation then how can I dismiss with Cancel button

Answer (score 14):

This Will do the trick

```
[actionSheet showInView:[self.view window]];
```

instead of

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 4):

use

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:[[self tabBarController] tabBar]];
```

instead of

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

this is working fine.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

write simplite code

```
 actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
```

this work fine

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1530259/1803218

```
[menu sendSubviewToBack:pickerView];
```