# UIActionsheet not dismissing

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet

I have 3 buttons in my UIActionsheet.
I want one cancel button at the bottom of it.

I also want that all of the buttons should be able to dismiss UIActionsheet.

Currently, none of them does the job for me.

Here is how I display it:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = nil;
NSArray *otherButtons = nil;


otherButtons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Button1", @"Button2", @"Button3",
                     nil];       

actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];


for( NSString *btntitle in otherButtons)
{
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:btntitle];
}    

[actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = actionSheet.numberOfButtons - 1;

actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

In my delegate, I do this:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
      //some code
      [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
}
```

But it does not dismiss. I do not want to change my design and position of any buttons. 
What should I do?

Comment: Got how to make the cancel button work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550579/uiactionsheet-cancel-button-not-dismissing-actionsheet. However other buttons still do not discard the sheet.

Comment: you did correctly. I am not sure where is the problem. but try only dismiss your actionsheet in - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex method. comment all other code inside that method. check whether it is working or nor.

Comment: I think you mentioned that you are doing some performance in - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex method. before dismiss. So avoid that.

Comment: if you want to do some operation while dismiss means do in a seperate function and call that function with "perform selector withdelay" method

Comment: it seems to be working but on second click, not the first. I did not understand your second comment. Do you mean the actual operation and dismissing should be in separate call? Also could you paste some code that will work irrespective of buttonIndex? because I need it on all buttons, including cancel.

Comment: hey, do you have tab bar in this view??

Comment: if you have any tab bar under the view means, try this, showFromTabBar:

Comment: I was having the same problem.  My action sheet was in a view controller inside a navigation controller inside a tab bar controller.  Following your link (and as SARANGA noted) I did as follows:  `[actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view]`.  It seems to have solved the problem.  Also, note that you shouldn't really need to dismiss explicitly.  You should be able to delete `[actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];`.  According to the documentation on `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex`, "The receiver is automatically dismissed after this method is invoked."

Comment: Tried both: [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.self.tabBarController.tabbar] and [actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view]. No success.

Comment: Tab bar seems to be the pointer though, because in other View controller of my app where there is no tab bar, an action sheet works just as expected without dismissing call.

Comment: What I observe here is that on first tap it focuses on the action sheet. On second tap it performs the button tap.

Comment: Which brings me to the conclusion: since I launch it on long press, it was launching twice!!! I just put a bool flag to know if it's launched already, and if yes, don't launch it again. Worked like charm! Thanks for the important pointers along the way! Dismissing wasn't required.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    [actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(OtherOperations) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];

}

-(void)OtherOperations{      //some code
}
```

Comment: I've a little concern here, what is going here that first of all you're dismissing and then executing a selector...really a nice hack but we really don't know what important stuff Nirav performed here so the case may be he wants the dismissing later if his task goes successfully and also in time of interruption we're not sure that selector will perform his task completely or not that why I suggest to start a new thread as it allocate from kernel, so distinct process...

Comment: It doesn't matter if sheet remains while operation is on or not. So this design is OK - however, it doesn't still serve any purpose. I still have to tap twice to dismiss it - first tap doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when opening an action sheet from a lpgr. Only open it on "Began", not again on "Ended".

```
- (void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tblYourVids];

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.aTable indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        if (indexPath == nil)
            NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
        else {
            NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
            self.selectedCell = [self.aTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            DLog(@"open action sheet only once");
            [self showActionSheet];
        }
    } else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // eat this one
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this to yours .h file.

```
 <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

Also add this line to yours .m file.

```
 actionSheet.delegate = self;
```

Let me know, this is working or not. If works, accept it as right answer

Comment: Ajay, Nirav is already assigning the delegate at the time when he is making the object of actionSheet, have you checked that so there's again no need of: actionSheet.delegate = self;

Answer (score -1):

just try to use the below code.it will automatically dismiss.

```
UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                         destructiveButtonTitle:@"Printer"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [sheet showInView:self.view];
    [sheet release];


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
}
```

let me know whether it is working or not

Happy Coding!!!!!

Comment: This doesn't do anything except putting an extra button. Try to resolve by code instead of suggesting design changes.

Answer (score -1):

This is not the right way to cancel `UIActionSheet` firstly you have to disable to default `UIActionSheet` by `javascipt` 
and go through this web

http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/07/11/customize-the-contextual-menu-of-uiwebview/

Comment: I am trying hard to understand the context my friend. Downvoted.

Comment: do you want the pop up when you tap on link and that shows UIACTIONSHEET options? is it na?? you want to add extra button on that?